# WPF Listview - Difficulty adding Items in List view

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a list view with grid-columns in **UserControl window** with file name **ListViewModel.xml**

```
    <GridView.Columns>
<GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Size" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}" />
     <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Last Modified" Width="170" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Modified}" />
      </GridView.Columns>
```

and I am populating directory file and folders in list view using this code in file **ListViewModel.xml.cs**

```
public void populateListView(string Path)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        counter = 0;
        DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path);

        List<UserList> items;

        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            items = new List<UserList>();
            items.Add(new UserList() { Name = dir.Name, Size = "", Type = dir.Extension.ToString(), Modified = dir.LastAccessTime.ToString() });

      //      listView1.Items.Add(new UserList() { Name = dir.Name, Size = "", Type = dir.Extension.ToString(), Modified = dir.LastAccessTime.ToString() });
            listView1.Items.Add(items);                                              
        }           

        foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            items = new List<UserList>();
            items.Add(new UserList() { Name = file.Name, Size = file.Length.ToString() + " bytes", Type = file.Extension, Modified = file.LastAccessTime.ToString() });
            listView1.Items.Add(items);                               
        }           
    }
```

while the directory path is sent through **TreeViewModel.xml.cs** as below

```
ListViewModel lm = new ListViewModel();                            
lm.populateListView(tagName); // tagName is path of directory
```

I bid the data  through **UserList.cs** as

```
public class UserList // model containing Properties for ListView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Size { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Modified { get; set; }
}
```

But I can't get see any content in the List-View? ANY HELP?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using DataColumn Binding you need to set the listview data context with your items

```
listView1.DataContext = items.ToList();
```

instead of using `listview1.Items.Add(...)`

Comment: still Couldn't get it. tried code like this:
items = new List<UserList>();


items.Add(new UserList() { Name = dir.Name, Size = "", Type = dir.Extension.ToString(), Modified = dir.LastAccessTime.ToString() });


listView1.DataContext = items.ToList();

Comment: can u give a short implementation ?